# Pass errorlevel from a child batch to parent

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Parent .bat

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set errorlevel=2

start /wait child.bat
echo %errorlevel%
```

Child .bat

```
set errorlevel=1
exit %errorlevel%
```

Output:

```
2
```

Expected Output:

```
1
```

The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095625/getting-errorlevel-from-a-called-batch-file) does not work for me, also I don't understand why you would use `/b` and leave the cmd open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No No No, don't ever use SET to assign your own value to ERRORLEVEL.

The issue is that ERRORLEVEL is not normally a true environment variable. It is a dynamic pseudo environment value that reflects the most recently returned ERRORLEVEL. But if you define your own true ERRORLEVEL environment variable using SET, then `%ERRORLEVEL%` will always return the value that you assigned, not the desired dynamic value.

This behavior is described within the help system. If you enter `set /?` or `help set` from the command line, then the following is printed at the end:

```
If Command Extensions are enabled, then there are several dynamic
environment variables that can be expanded but which don't show up in
the list of variables displayed by SET.  These variable values are
computed dynamically each time the value of the variable is expanded.
If the user explicitly defines a variable with one of these names, then
that definition will override the dynamic one described below:

%CD% - expands to the current directory string.

%DATE% - expands to current date using same format as DATE command.

%TIME% - expands to current time using same format as TIME command.

%RANDOM% - expands to a random decimal number between 0 and 32767.

%ERRORLEVEL% - expands to the current ERRORLEVEL value

%CMDEXTVERSION% - expands to the current Command Processor Extensions
    version number.

%CMDCMDLINE% - expands to the original command line that invoked the
    Command Processor.

%HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER% - expands to the highest NUMA node number
    on this machine.
```

If you want to define a variable to hold an error code that will later be used by EXIT or EXIT /B, then use a different name. I like to use ERR.

If you ever find that someone has mistakenly defined ERRORLEVEL, then you can clear it and restore the desired functionality by using `set "errorlevel="`.

If you want to explicitly set ERRORLEVEL to a specific value without calling a subroutine, then you can use one of the following techniques:

Set the value to 0: `(call )`

Set the value to 1: `(call)`

Set the value to any number (I'll use 56): `cmd /c exit 56`

Comment: Ah in my child script I tried different iterations which included _exit 5_ but since in my parent I set the variable manually it couldn't work! Thanks for your reply.